# Proof of Approximation Ratio of Greedy Algorithm to Set Cover.

Tags: algorithms, approximation

I am reading the book "Approximation Algorithm" by Vijay V Vazirani
http://athena.nitc.ac.in/~kmurali/Courses/CombAlg2014/vazirani.pdf

And in proof of Lemma 2.3, the author said
"In the iteration in which $e_k$ was covered, $\overline{C}$ contained at least $n-k+1$ elements." without any claims.

But this is not so trivial for me. Can anyone give me some hint or explain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on the fact that you update the sets in the following in each iteration in the following manner:
Let $\hat{S}_i$ be the set with the minimum cost-effectiveness. Then update for all sets which indices are not yet added to the solution index set 
 $\hat{S}_{j}= \hat{S}_{j} - \hat{S}_{i}$ $\forall j \neq i$. Therefore no set will contain the elements which are already added and hence in each iteration at least one new element is covered by the solution. Then you have trivially $\frac{1}{n-k+1}$ elements left at the start of the $k$-th iteration.